# SQL SUM BEST VALUES FROM TABLE AND UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

i wanted to know how can i do this example please:

i have tow tables:

```
user(id_user, points, id_subligue)

subligue(id_subligue, points)
```

how can i get the two best user by points and group by id_subligue, sum an add in subligue table.

example:

```
user
(
     user1, 10, 1; 
     user2, 15, 1; 
     user3, 20, 1; 
     user4, 10, 2;
     user 5, 20, 2,
     user6, 30, 2; 
     user7, 40, 2
)

subligue
(
   1, 35; 
   2, 70
)
```

i tried that:

```
select      SUM(user.points) AS TOTAL

from       (SELECT user.points 
            FROM user
            ORDER BY user.points DESC
            LIMIT 2
            ) user
```

but i dont know how to update subligue table with TOTAL and by id_subligue

Sorry if i dont explain very well, i ll answer any questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main question is: why would you want to do this? The data is already there so why put it redundantly in another?

Comment: Which DBMS are you asking this for? Please tag it.

Comment: I need the dato in Subligue table to do a clasification by subligues by points. Is in MySQL php

Comment: Note that the shift button on your keyboard is meant to be used often for single letters, usually according to the english grammar.

Comment: Yes Stefan. Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding the below query will give you the desire result

```
Select user.id_user,SUM(subligue.points) AS TOTAL from user inner join subligue on user.id_subligue=subligue.id_subligue
order by subligue.points DESC
```

//New Solution

```
select   SUM(user.points) AS TOTAL
from     (Select top 2  user.points from user inner join subligue on user.id_subligue=subligue.id_subligue
order by  user.points DESC ) user
```

//We can use where clause for getting specific result for id_subligue

```
select   SUM(user.points) AS TOTAL
from     (Select top 2  user.points from user inner join subligue on user.id_subligue=subligue.id_subligue where user.id_subligue=1 
order by  user.points DESC ) user
```

As Question is not very clear to me and if this above solution do not working then let me know the final output you want.

Comment: Hi, thank very much. That doesnt work. My wish output is: on subligue table, on points field, has the sum of the two best score points from user with the same id_subligue.

Comment: @agustincola Now please try this and let me know the output

Comment: Hi again. Thank u very much for your help. Now i only get for one subligue. But i need for each subligue. I get subligue 1 = 35 points, but i dont get about subligue 2. I think we have to use GROUP BY. Sorry and i appreciate your help.

Comment: @agustincola just change the value in where clause for example "2" and then you can get the points for sublingue 2

Comment: @agustincola And please mark solution as answer or vote up if the above solution really help you.

Comment: Okk Thank you Anarug! Respect! Thanks for your time!

Comment: @agustincola Thanks